# Android Studio project folders not showing

Tags: android-studio, directory

I am unable to see the folders that are physically existing, this is the case.

[image]

But in actual fact I have other folders as welll
[image]

So what can I do?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Above your the file directory view in Android Studio is a drop down which currently is most likely set to Android. Change it to Project and you should be able to see all your files.

[image: Android Studio Directory]

Comment: Yeah, this is the first impulse.  But what do you do when you ALREADY have "Project Files" selected, yet folders are STILL not displayed?  Android Studio 2.1.2.

Comment: @ScottBiggs I have the same issue. All is shows is external libraries.

Comment: @Sethmr: it seems that Android Studio simply doesn't show empty folders.  Sigh.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, but no one on here lead me in the right direction.

Comment: As @ScottBiggs says, with some AS versions (2.3) changing to Project, or ProjectFiles does not help. But leaving the option on "Project" and restarting AS 2.3 helped in my case :)  HTH 2U2

Comment: Why on earth are some folders not showing in the regular tree view on the left?

Answer (score 15):

I tried the all the approaches mentioned above but can't fix rather than fix it by a hardcore approach -

**Step 1.** Close your Android studio.

**Step 2.** Delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folder from your project directory.

**Step 3.** Open your project and you will see the files again.

Comment: Nice one, that did the trick for me after all other suggestions (clear caches, gradle sync,...) failed!

Answer (score 13):

go to View menu then click tool window  then after click on project

view->toolwindow->project

it worked for me

Comment: this topic is closed!

Answer (score 7):

for me doing the following works:

from menu go to:  View--->tool windows ---> Project

then click the little gears icon (settings) you will see an option to change the empty middle packages. it looks like this:

[image]

disable "Hide Empty Middle Packages" under the Project View settings dropdown and then it should make everything show up.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever does what I did maybe this will help:

Android Studio does not like it when module names begin with a number. I was learning from some tutorials and named the first module "1-name" and the next one "2-name". Setup was fine and it ran, but only the "Gradle" Scripts entry would show in the navigation window in "Android" mode.