# Android Studio - cannot create libs directory

Tags: android-studio, directory

I want to create libs directory to my project, but there is no option in context menu to create it! There is image: http://bit.ly/1vhLGn1
If I choose "folder" item - there are standard folders only, no lubs folder. Android Studion version 0.8.14

What I do wrong?

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902867/android-studio-project-folders-not-showing/26904723#26904723 you should be able to change to Project view. Then you can create a Directory.

Answer (score 1):

Select your mode as **Project**, then create new **Directory** as "Libs" or whatever new Folder you want, just create.